# Prove that if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is such that every point of the set {$1/n:n\in{N}$} is a limit of some subsequence, then $0$ is also

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is such that every point of the set {$1/n:n\in{N}$} is a limit of some subsequence, then $0$ is also a limit point.

I'm not asking for an answer. I'm just looking for some guidance. For starters, I know the statement is saying that $\{1,1/2, 1/3, 1/4,....\}$ is the limit of some subsequence of $\{a_n\}$. Other than that, I am at a loss for where to even start.

Comment: From each subsequence, find a point within $\frac1n$ of $\frac1n$. Why does this help you...

Comment: @RushabhMehta. So every subsequence converges to some $1/n$. Is this equivalent to proving 1/n converges to 0? I'm not sure how to formally write up the bit about subsequences. I think I conceptually understand what it is saying.

Comment: Recall that a sequence a has a limit point $L$ (i.e. a subsequence converges to $L$) if and only if $L$ is an accumulation point for the range of the sequence. The set of accumulation points is closed. So, given $1, 1/2, 1/3, \ldots$ are all accumulation points, so too is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to try to clear up some of your confusion and state things a little more precisely. Saying $\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}$ *is the limit* of some subsequence is inaccurate. Better is to say that for each point of $\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}$, there is a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ which converges to that point. In your comment to Rushabh Mehta, you say "every subsequence converges to some $1/n$." This is also inaccurate. Better would be to say that for each $1/n$, *there is a subsequence* that converges to $1/n$. For there are indeed subsequences that are not even convergent!

---

Now, it is given to us that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ has the property that for each $k = 1, 2, 3, \dots$, there is a subsequence $\{a_1^{(k)},a_2^{(k)},a_3^{(k)},\dots\}$ such that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{(k)} = \frac{1}{k}.
$$
We want a subsequence $\{a_1^{(0)},a_2^{(0)},a_3^{(0)},\dots\}$ of $\{a_n\}$ with the property that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{(0)} = 0.
$$

Here is a hint for how to proceed: Since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{(1)} = 1,
$$
choose $n_1$ sufficiently large so that $a_{n_1}^{(1)} \in \big(1-\frac{1}{2^1},1+\frac{1}{2^1}\big)$. Set $a_1^{(0)} = a_{n_1}^{(1)}$.

Next, since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{(2)} = \frac{1}{2},
$$
choose $n_2>n_1$ sufficiently large so that $a_{n_2}^{(2)}$ comes after $a_{n_1}^{(1)}$ in the original sequence $\{a_n\}$, and $a_{n_2}^{(2)} \in \big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}\big)$. Set $a_2^{(0)} = a_{n_2}^{(2)}$.

Next, since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{(3)} = \frac{1}{3},
$$
... (you take it from here.)

Once you have constructed the sequence $\{a_n^{(0)}\}$, prove that it converges to $0$. (Eventually it is less than any given $1/n$, and every term in it is positive.)

Comment: I see what you are doing here. Thanks. Actually the given problem states that every point of 1/n is a limit of some subsequence. So, are you suggesting the problem is using inaccurate language?

Comment: @MathGuy: That language is fine. What was said in the original post was that *the set* $\{1/n\}$ is *a limit* of some subsequence. That's not just inaccurate, it actually doesn't make sense. Of course, that's just being nitpick-y. It seems like everyone is aware of what is intended.